# How to work with local website secured by SSL on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, nginx, https, openssl

I would like that my local websites are secured by SSL. So I maked all the stuff for that : add Self-Signed SSL Certificate and configure nginx. At the end, my website work properly with HTTPS on Safari but not on Google Chrome, it said that my "connection is not privated". There is a particular thing to do for that ?
You can find my nginx conf file below :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    

    # substitute your web server's local URL with yours
    

    index                           index.html index.php;

    access_log              /usr/local/var/log/nginx/mysite.com.access.log;
    error_log               /usr/local/var/log/nginx/mysite.com.error.log;
    client_max_body_size 128m;

    # substitute your web server's root folder with yours
    root                /usr/local/www/mysite;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files                   $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index               index.php;
        fastcgi_param               SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout        300;
        fastcgi_keep_conn           on;
        include                     /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    # Php-fpm is bound to port 9001
        fastcgi_pass                127.0.0.1:9000;
        index                       index.html index.php;
    }

    location / {
        try_files                   $uri
                                    $uri/
                                    /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

And here is the "params-ssl.conf" file :

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 80.67.169.12 80.67.169.40 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubdomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
ssl_dhparam /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

Thank you !

Killian

Comment: Is there not a "proceed anyway" button? I think you can also click the button on the page and then type out "thisisunsafe". https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB

Answer (score 0):

If you can arrange for your machine to have a public DNS name and be accessible from the internet (for the verification process), then you can get a free certificate **signed by a real CA** from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

The advantage of this method is that it does not require any configuration of the browsers that will be accessing the server.